# How to diagnose module error in terminal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently trying to create a new Alexa skill through the Amazon ask-cli, and I am running into an issue with a seemingly simple task. When I run `ask init`, I get the following error in terminal:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ask-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:18:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ask-cli/node_modules/bunyan/lib/bunyan.js:79:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I suppose this means I need to install something via npm, but am not able to find a package called `DTraceProviderBindings`. I installed `dtrace-provider`, but still get the same error when I try to run `ask init`. So how can I diagnose and solve this, and other problems like it?